# Custom loss function in Keras (asymmetric MAE)

Tags: keras, loss-function

I am trying to implement a custom loss function for Keras LSTM, which would represent asymmetric MAE (penalizing right shift and rewarding left shift of a prediction in relation to actuals).  What is the syntax considering the input parameters are tensors, not numpy arrays?

```
def amae(a, p):
    product = a
    product[1:] = a[1:] - a[:-1]
    product[0] = 0
    product = -product*10
    delta = p - a
    delta = abs(delta) + (delta * product)

    return sum(delta)/len(delta)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could try:

```py
def amae(a, p):
    delta = p - a
    
    # Get row of booleans where predicted is higher than actual e.g. 1 - 0
    penalty = tf.greater(delta, 0) 
    # Cast float to mathematically do some math
    penalty = tf.cast(penalize_right_shift, tf.float16) 
    
    # Penalize by a factor of 10x
    penalty = penalty * 9 + 1 # Add +1 even to 0 since will use this as multiplier
    
    # squared difference
    sq_delta = tf.square(delta)

    return tf.reduce_mean(penalty * sq_delta, axis=-1)
```